# Merge transparent PNG to an empty white background, ends up in black background

Tags: php

I use the script below to make images rectangles. The problem is I came across some transparent .png images, that when saved as .jpg by my script, the transparency is turned to black, although I specifically use a white background image. What am I doing wrong?

```
fix_image( '0008982_0.png' );

function fix_image( $src_file ) {
    $src_img = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/' . $src_file ) );

    $img_x = imagesx( $src_img );
    $img_y = imagesy( $src_img );

    $square_xy = ( $img_x > $img_y ) ? $img_x : $img_y;

    $final_image = imagecreatetruecolor( $square_xy, $square_xy );
    $background  = imagecolorallocate( $final_image, 255, 255, 255 );

    imagefilledrectangle( $final_image, 0, 0, $square_xy, $square_xy, $background );

    if ( $img_x > $img_y ) {
        $dst_x = 0;
        $dst_y = ( $square_xy - $img_y ) / 2;
    } elseif ( $img_y > $img_x ) {
        $dst_x = ( $square_xy - $img_x ) / 2;
        $dst_y = 0;
    } else {
        $dst_x = 0;
        $dst_y = 0;
    }

    $src_x = 0;
    $src_y = 0;

    $src_w = $img_x;
    $src_h = $img_y;

    $pct = 100;

    imagecopymerge( $final_image, $src_img, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct );
    imagejpeg( $final_image, __DIR__ . '/' . pathinfo( $src_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) . '.jpg', 75 );
    imagedestroy( $src_img );
    imagedestroy( $final_image );
}
```

If you want to try my script, please use the attached image.

[image]